# Python: retrieve column from a table as dictionary using SQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 in my python code to do a 
SELCT column1,column2 from a postgres table.

I would like to store the o/p of the query as a dictionary with column1 as the key and column2 as value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished easily using pythons inbuilt `dict()` functions.
I'm assuming the result is stored in a variable `sql_result` in my example, but you can change it to the variable with your SQL result:

```
sql_result = [
    [1, "A"],
    [2, "B"],
    [3, "C"]
    ]

res = dict(sql_result)
print(res)
```